# Parsing a JSON string to an integer in Elixir

Tags: parsing, error-handling, elixir

I'm dealing with a JSON API that returns a number as a string. For example `"12"`, however, this field value could also be non-numeric, for example: `"-"`.

I've parsed the JSON data into a map and I want to extract this field to as an integer in elixir, and then perform some operation depending on where the integer falls in a certain range.

There seem to be multiple ways to do this the two main being `Integer.parse/1`, which returns a tuple or `:error`, and `String.to_integer/1`, which returns the integer or raises an exception.

What is the best way to perform some operation based on where the numeric value contained inside a string falls in a certain range, handling parsing errors appropriately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one expects the value can be not an integer (under normal, not exceptional circumstances,) one should use [`Integer.parse/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Integer.html#parse/2):

```
analysis =
  case Integer.parse(string_value_from_json) do
    {i, ""} when i in 1..10 ->
      "integer #{i} between 1 and 10"
    {i, ""} when i in 11..20 ->
      "integer #{i} is between 11 and 20"
    {i, ""} ->
      "integer #{i} was out of range"
    _ -> "integer could not be parsed"
  end
```

Throwing and handling an exception should be left as a last resort and is discouraged to be used to control a flow.

Answer (score -1):

The documentation for `Integer.parse` says to use `String.to_integer` for this purpose, so it's probably best to follow the guidelines:

> If you want to convert a string-formatted integer directly to a
>   integer, `String.to_integer/1` or `String.to_integer/2` can be used
>   instead.

However, `String.to_integer` raises an error if the string cannot be parsed. Error cases can be caught and assigned to `nil`, then the result pattern-matched over:

```
integer_value =
  try do
    String.to_integer(string_value_from_json)
  rescue
    _ -> nil
  end

analysis =
  case integer_value do
    nil -> "integer could not be parsed"
    integer_value when integer_value in 1..10 -> "integer #{integer_value} between 1 and 10"
    integer_value when integer_value in 11..20 -> "integer #{integer_value} is between 11 and 20"
    integer_value -> "integer #{integer_value} was out of range"
  end

IO.puts analysis
```

Comment: The documentation **does not say to use `String.to_integer`**, it says “it can be used,” and in this particular case this is wrong. Throwing and handling an exception should be left as a last resort. If you expect the value to be sometimes not integer, you should use `Integer.parse`.

Comment: I see, I initially wanted to Integer.parse but its document persuaded me otherwise. I guess I the exceptional circumstances in this case should have been more of a deciding factor.